# Is there any responsive way to add watermark to canvas using fabric.js?

Tags: click, fabricjs, watermark

I'm recently working on a project using fabric.js, the element in the canvas can drag stretch and etc, i need to add a watermark on the canvas that won't affect my element, and make it able to click through the watermark, is there any example of it?

Comment: what do you mean by responnsive way?

Comment: like, when image capturing can exclude the watermark

Answer (score 0):

add your image as watermark, put it as

```
watermark.evented = false;
```

to make it not interacting with mouse clicks and selections.